# Database connection lost once stopped by ctrl-z?

Tags: database

I stopped a php program by ctrl-z, and `bg 1` right away, but the connection seems not valid any more.

Isn't `sleep` supposed to restore all resources correctly?

Comment: Shore, this belongs on Serverfault.

Comment: Also a bit of Google would help. A quick search of "PHP MySQL sleep" uncovered alot of answers.

Answer (score 2):

The local state is preserved when you stop a process, but the state of remote resources obviously cannot be maintained. If the remote MySQL instance times out the connection you need to reconnect.